# Grunt override init task from register task

Tags: gruntjs

I've grunt file with init etc, I want to create some register task which override some configuration (init etc) how it's suggested to do it ?

I've found the following but not sure if it's good to use it for my purpose 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-config-merge

e.g. I've **threshold** for unit testing and I want to be able to update it via **task and not manually ...**

For example I want to create task which modify the **dest value**

```js
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    copy: {
        production: {
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    flatten: true,
                    src: ["test/testcontent/plugins/*"],
                    dest: "plugins/"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

Comment: You need to edit your question and provide the relevant parts of your `Gruntfile.js`.  How your question is currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking for. Provide further detail/example(s) on exactly what you're trying to achieve. By doing so you'll greater your chance of getting an answer/solution.

Comment: @RobC - please see my update\